# accessing point[] method in a getter

Tags: java

I am trying to access a Point[] getter method in another method but the error I am getting is on the first vertex[0].x which states that I cannot have this for a point but when I insert parenthesis, I get more errors.

```
public double getArea() {
    Point[] vertex = getVertices();
    double area = ((vertex[0].x, vertex[1].y - vertex[0].y, vertex[1].x +
            vertex[1].x, vertex[2].y - vertex[1].y, vertex[2].x +
            vertex[2].x, vertex[3].y - vertex[2].y, vertex[3].x +
            vertex[3].x, vertex[4].y - vertex[3].y, vertex[4].x +
            vertex[4].x, vertex[5].y - vertex[4].y, vertex[5].x +
            vertex[5].x, vertex[0].y - vertex[5].y, vertex[0].x/2)));

    return Math.abs(area);
}
```

Here is a snippet of the method that contains the array:

```
public Point[] getVertices() {
    int x = this.getXPosition();
    int y = this.getYPosition();
    Point[] vertex = new Point[6];
    Point p1 = new Point(x+this.getWidth()/2, y);
    vertex[0] = p1;
    Point p2 = new Point(x+this.getWidth(), y+(this.getHeight()/3));
    vertex[1] = p2;
```

Comment: In first snippet you pass two arguments to `getVertices`, while in the second snippet it accepts zero arguments.

Comment: What is the exact error message and show us the line where you get it (hint: use a comment like this: ` // <<<--- here`. Also the method definition for `getVertices()` doesn't match the usage. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `getVertices()` method, which is declared with no arguments, and you pass multiple arguments in the call (`vertex[1].x` etc). So what you are doing here is accessing the `vertices` directly, but in the method call.

What you could do is either something like `getVertices()[0].x`, or just access them directly.